# how to use min-width, max-width and width 100%

Tags: html, css, width

Anybody please help me describing a suitable example of min-width max-width and width 100% and why should I use this specially for?

**Edit**

what should I use for min-width that most computers resolution may match.
what should I use for max-width that most computers resolution may match.

**Edit**
I need better example as yahoo.com use

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Did you already try something and can share your code?

Comment: No! I just want to learn about it perfectly.

Comment: Now check to this example and minmize for min width check demo is here http://tinkerbin.com/CKh27l9D  more info http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/width.html

Comment: Great question, shouldn't have closed

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**min-width:** If you set it 50px, then by default your div will be of width 50px. If the content inside the div has more width than 50px, then it(your div with min-width) will expand.

**max-width:** If you set it 50px and if the content inside the div has more width than 50px, then it(your div with max-width) will not expand, a horizontal scroll may appear depending on your overflow settings.

**width:100%** By default divs are of width 100% but if you have floating divs and you want to them to take all the horizontal space of their container, width:100% does help there.

Comment: I have voted your answer as it describes perfectly about that. But actually I want that what if we use them? By using % should we consider all other contents to be in %?

Comment: Hmm.. about %, You can use it like <div style="width:200px"><div style="width:80%"></div></div> and this will work perfectly well. You can always mix n match % with px.

Answer (score 6):

it's very general, but:

- **min-width** is very useful in cases in which you have width set in % and you don't want to your element be too small.

  ```
  <div style="100%">
      <div style="width:30%;min-width:50px;"></div>
  </div>
  ```

So if parent div will be to small, child will have at least 50px.

Or you can use it if div is dependent of parent window width. Min-width has higher priority than width and max-width.

- **max-width** can be used in similar way.
- **width:100%** is explained in details here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/

Answer (score 2):

**min-width:**

the minimum width of the div, it will never be smaller as the width given.

if min-width:50px the div will always be minimum 50 px or bigger.

if min-width:50% the div will be 50% of the object its in.

( if its in a div of 1200px it will be 600px)

( if the first div  it will be 50% of the screen)

**max-width**

is the same as minimum but now it will never be bigger instead of never smaller.
so if:

max-width:50%

the div wil never be bigger then 50% of the object its in.

if
you use % if you want the page to look exactly the same on each resolution.

if you have 1 div  with width 80%

```
 <div id="1">
```

and 1 div in it with width 50%

```
   <div id="2">
```

div 2 will be 50% of 80 % so it will be 40% of the total page.

min-width and max width can be used if you have a div with no width:

the div will be betweeen the min-width and max-width then, depending on the content.

if you use width:100% it makes the div 100% the width of the object its in.

if its the first div its the full width of the screen.

if it is in a div with width:500px  the div will be 100% of 500 px so 500px

Comment: If I use % then font size and other sizes are also to be used in % for better performance?

Comment: if you have overflow:auto in the div it wont matter cause the div wil be scrollable and adjust its hight to the content. you shouldnt use % for font size.

Comment: I see yahoo pages are perfect in any resolution and they have fixed width too. How to do like that?

Comment: you can set the div with in css to 50% the div with that css will always be 50% of the screen. so it depends on the resolution. if you give all your divs the good % it will look the some on every resolution (also on phones) if you se width in px the width wont adjust to the resolution. its always (example width:250px)  250px even if the screen is 100 px. but if you use width:50% it will be 50px on a screen of 100 px   600 px on a screen of 1200 px.

Comment: without resizing does it work if we apply %, any method? please!

Comment: I mean Yahoo.com has full width in any resolution but without resizing its contents. How do they do?

Comment: they have a width in px. so it will always be the same size.

Comment: So, which method should I use?

Comment: If you want it like yahoo use px for size. if you want it to adjust to screen resolution use %

Comment: if your question is answered click the V at the answer ur liked most, if not answered tell what you want to know more.

Comment: I know your concepts perfectly but I needed to consider what types of pages should be considered in using % min-width and max-width? And I have voted you up coz that little thing I must accept.

Comment: you should try both, you also can combine.    give a menu a width in px and the content in % is preferable

Answer (score 1):

**`min-width`** is used to fix the minimum width, after the given extent of the width value, div will start expanding automatically

**`max-width`** is used to give maximum width after that extent div will not get extends.

**`width:100%`** extends the div to the available space of the browser/parent element